# Pack a class containing a std::array of packed non-POD elements

Tags: c++

I have a class with an explicit constructor to enable stronger typing.

I want another class to be able to include a `std::array` of these objects and also be packed.

```
class __attribute__((packed)) NonPOD {
  private:
    int m_i;
  public:
    explicit NonPOD(int i) : m_i(i) {}
};

class __attribute__((packed)) PackedDownstream {
  private:
    NonPOD a[2];
};

class __attribute__((packed)) PackedDownstreamWithStdArray {
  private:
    std::array<NonPOD, 2> a;
};

class __attribute__((packed)) POD {
  public:
    int m_i;
}

class __attribute__((packed)) PackedPOD {
  private:
    std::array<POD, 2> a;
}
```

In this code snippet, only `PackedDownstreamWithStdArray` refuses to be packed, with g++ 9 and --std=c++17, complaining:

```
warning: ignoring packed attribute because of unpacked non-POD field ‘std::array<NonPod, 2> PackedDownstreamWithStdArray::a’
```

Is there a way to both (a) force an explicit constructor and (b) use a class in a packed `std::array`?

Comment: Do note that `std::array` itself may have padding and you can't do anything about that.